# How to iterate html div in any number of times in knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockoutJS in my e-commerce. There is a function `getCartParam("summary_count")` which returns an integer value as number of added product in a cart.
Based on this integer value, I want to generate same number of divs in my html.

For example, If `getCartParam("summary_count")` is returning 10 than I want to make a loop in knockout foreach to generate 10 divs.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: getCartParam("summary_count")">
    <li data-bind="text : $index()"></li>
</ul>
```

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `foreach` binding with a new Array:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: new Array(getCartParam('summary_count'))">
    <li data-bind="text : $index()"></li>
</ul>
```

Be sure that `getCartParam('summary_count')` returns a number though, because if it does not there will be no javascript error but you will end up with an Array of one element only.

See [**doc**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)